# Unable to create DirectX D3D context. Neither Hardware and Software are available

Tags: java, java-3d

I am trying to import one 3D model of aircraft in java GUI using java3D.It is running fine in my pc.I have created a jar file for it to run on any pc using netbeans. when I tried running this jar file in other pc it is throwing following error:

> Unable to create DirectX D3D context. Neither Hardware and Software
>   are available. Please update your video card drivers and get the
>   latest DirectX available at http://microsoft.com/directx

What could be the  possible reason for the above issue and how to solve it.

Comment: Do other 3D programs (eg games) work?

Comment: @immibis never tried as it's lab pc, Do you think the problem is due to graphic drivers are outdated?

Comment: I checked, it is not allowing me to run any other java 3D programme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your program uses Java3D 1.6.0 instead of Java3D 1.5.2 or earlier (which seems to be the case). Then, install a proper OpenGL driver (get it from the website of the GPU manufacturer, NVidia, AMD or Intel). Look at those tutorials to use Java3D 1.6.0 and make fat JARs:

http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D

http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling#Fat-Jar

The maintenance of Java3D 1.5.2 has been stopped several years ago. The JogAmp community maintains only Java3D 1.6.0 as stated here:

http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Java3D_Overview

http://forum.jogamp.org/JogAmp-s-Java3D-continuation-Java3D-1-6-0-and-later-td4030907.html

Java3D 1.6.0 doesn't rely on Direct3D unlike Java3D 1.5.2. It uses **exclusively** JOGL to access to hardware acceleration.

Your current message indicates that there is no available driver or that the current one is outdated. Nevertheless, I don't advise you to use an obsolete version of Java3D anyway.

Comment: I am not able to implement what you are saying. I downloaded java 3D 1.6 verson jar files and added it to java path also dowloaded corresponding .dll libraries and put it in java.library.path. but still I am getting following error
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/nativewindow/CapabilitiesChooser

Comment: I think the problem was not using current version of Java3D, but now I don't know how to install Java 3D in Netbeans

Comment: @Ranjan You haven't followed my tutorial, there is no DLL to download, there is no need to set the Java library path and your installation must be clean in order to avoid any conflict with an older version of Java3D and/or JOGL. JOGL uses GlueGen which picks the right JARs, extract and load the native libraries from them. Please follow the steps described in my tutorial instead of guessing what you have to do: http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/

Comment: For Netbeans, it's explained in this subsection: https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/#netbeans Don't go too fast, read carefully what I wrote and it will work.

Comment: Hi @gouessej I am not able to understand this part of your tutorial:

You just have to copy all JARs above into the same directory (so that JogAmp knows where to find the native libraries during the automatic extraction and loading)

How will I come to know that which directory is OK for JogAmp to find the native library?

What I did I will tell you:
EX_3D is my project;
I put all jars mentioned in ur tutorial in D:\Ranjan\EX_3D\lib
I added all those non native jars to project by right click on libraries->add jar/folder

Comment: After this I tried running my project but got below error 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLException

Comment: The JARs of the Java libraries used by JOGL must be in the same directory than the JARs of the native libraries used by JOGL, i.e jogl-all.jar must be in the same directory than jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar for example. Java3D will become easier to install in the near future as it will be possible to use a single JAR for JOGL (jogamp-fat.jar).

Comment: You haven't cleaned your machine, there is still a conflict with an old version of Java3D as javax.media.opengl comes from an old version of JOGL whereas Java3D 1.6.0 pre12 and later do NOT use javax.media.opengl.

Comment: what should I do to clean my system?

Comment: You should uninstall all obsolete versions of Java3D before installing the latest version in order to avoid any conflict. If you don't do it, the Java runtime environment will go on picking an obsolete version of Java3D and complain about not finding a class of an obsolete version of JOGL located in the packages javax.media.*. According to your error message, there is still at least one obsolete version of Java3D in your JRE, in a directory used by the extension mechanism or in any directory mentioned in your classpath. Look for j3dcore.jar in your computer.

Comment: I tried running the same project in another system which don't have j3dcore.jar. In that system Java 3d has never been used,But it shows the same error.

Comment: The project must be run with the latest version of Java3D and JOGL 2 in its classpath. If you still get a NoClassDefFoundError on GLException, it might indicate that the project was compiled with an obsolete version of Java3D depending on an obsolete version of JOGL, maybe it is bundled with a version of Java3D. The very latest version of Java3D never looks for anything in the package "javax.media", there is something wrong in your project. Java3D 1.6.0 works very well and as its public API remains mostly unchanged, any Java3D application works with it as long as the JARs are in the classpath.

Comment: @Rajan There is still something in your project that tries to use some classes in the package "javax.media". Java3D 1.6.0 pre 12 doesn't.

Comment: can you give me one sample project of java 3D in Netbeans which runs smoothly, So that I can figure out the difference

Comment: Yes, I have to import javax.media.* because it is required for the source code. but I am using recent java 3D jars from http://jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/1.6.0-pre12/
I can see that javax.media library is there inside these jar files. Then how, you are saying that Java 3D don't use javax.media.* . actually I am using Canvas3D class. Netbeans is suggesting me to use javax.media.* library.

Comment: Pls tell me If I have to use Canvas3D, How should I import the class?

Comment: Numerous classes of Java 3D are still in the package "javax.media" but Java3D 1.6.0 pre 12 doesn't use javax.media.opengl and javax.media.nativewindow (from obsolete versions of JOGL). Therefore, the class GLException (JOGL) should be found, you shouldn't get a NoClassDefFoundError. Sorry for the confusion. My detailed instructions in my tutorial allows to create a Netbeans project from scratch using Java3D and JOGL. As long as there is still an obsolete version of Java3D loaded in priority (in your classpath or installed as an extension), you won't be able to use the latest version.

Comment: Please check that you have added the right JARs into your classpath. Several months ago, a young developer wasted a lot of time because he mixed some JARs downloaded on the Oracle website with some JogAmp's JARs instead of strictly following my instructions.

Comment: The following JARs should be in your classpath: gluegen-rt.jar, j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, joal.jar, jogl-all.jar and vecmath.jar. joal.jar is optional, the others are mandatory. Look at the tab "Projects" in Netbeans, your project should look like this one (+ the JARs of Java3D): http://jogamp.org/wiki/images/8/89/NetBeans_setup_03_libraries_in_project.png

Comment: Pls forward one sample java3D project (netbeans)to my email id 
naliniranjan01@gmail.com
then only I'll be able to correlate. 
What you are saying, I have done it again and again but not working for me

Comment: Please indicate which error message you get. If you still get a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLException", erase all Java3D JARs from your machine, look at the extensions and the classpath, reinstall it again. Java3D doesn't use "javax.media.opengl" as you can see here: https://github.com/hharrison/java3d-core/commit/d4925af4fb2eda60837d37e8be6f62fd562fb23c If you don't succeed in removing the obsolete version that causes the conflicts, even a simple Netbeans project using Java 3D 1.6.0 won't work (for example if there is still an old JAR in jre/lib/ext).

Comment: Instead of asking for a Netbeans project, please tell us which error message you get. If we don't understand what is wrong, we can't help you.

Comment: I am getting the same error as you mentioned java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLException"  but I want one java project of netbeans so that I can run it on diff pc where Java 3D has never been used. If it runs I'll compare the environment of both pc and resolve the issue.

Comment: I have tried deleting all jar file and adding new Jar mentioned above. it didn't work

Comment: Therefore, I see only two possibilities. Either you assume that you're using Java3D 1.6.0 pre12 whereas the JARs you're using come from another version or the obsolete version is still elsewhere on your machine. Providing a Netbeans project wouldn't help if this obsolete version was outside of this project. Please can you try to create a project from scratch on another machine? If it works, it will prove that there is something wrong only on one particular machine.

Comment: I've just checked the bytecode of the class file JoglPipeline.class, it refers to com/jogamp/opengl/GLException in Java3D 1.6.0 pre12. You can check it too, look at jogamp-java3d.7z, in j3dcore.jar.

Comment: Hi,
in my j3dcore.jar in JoglPipeline.class it refers to javax/media/opengl/GLException

I downloaded this jar from http://jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/1.6.0-pre12/

Comment: Is this the cause of error? It should refer to com/jogamp/opengl/GLException ?

Comment: j3dcore.jar from jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/1.6.0-pre12 doesn't refer to javax/media/opengl/GLException, it hasn't been updated since April 2015, it refers to com/jogamp/opengl/GLException, I've just checked it once more in j3dcore.jar and in jogamp-java3d.7z. You downloaded several versions of Java3D and you picked the wrong one but you believed that the JARs you put into your Netbeans project came from the right location. Yes, you use the wrong JARs, it points out to a wrong package, it is the cause of your NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Please erase the JARs coming from the wrong version of Java3D, download http://jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/1.6.0-pre12/jogamp-java3d.7z, uncompress this archive and follow the instructions on my blog, it just works.

Comment: Yeah it worked. Still surprised with the way I got my problem solved.

Comment: But when I am trying to run it on diiferent PC through executable jar created by the Netbeans I am getting following error:

javax.media.j3d.IllegalRenderingStateException: Java 3D ERROR : OpenGL 1.2 or better is required (GL_VERSION=1.1)

Comment: The error message is crystal clear, this PC can't run Java3D because it supports only OpenGL 1.1 whereas Java3D requires at least OpenGL 1.2. Most of the time, it can be fixed by installing a proper OpenGL driver. This different PC only has "Microsoft GDI Renderer" as a driver that emulates OpenGL 1.1 through Direct3D. Look at my original answer again: "install a proper OpenGL driver (get it from the website of the GPU manufacturer, NVidia, AMD or Intel)". If you follow my advise, it will work on this PC too. Don't give up :)